# xmlstarlet select value of an attribute based on value of other attribute in a every <JOB> tag iteration

Tags: shell, scripting, xmlstarlet

While using the below command within my Code to extract a parameter FTP-RHOST , I am not able to extract it and the Script assigns Blank value for the variable , the below two lines are part of a larger script where I am building an XML based on an another Input XML :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//JOB['"$i"']/AUTOEDIT2[@NAME='FTP-RHOST']/@VALUE' ~testhwa/FTPJobstable007.xml >> /tmp/FTRSERVER

FTRSERVER=`cat /tmp/FTRSERVER`
```

Input XML (consisting of multiple tags of  and ) :

```
<JOB
     ACTIVE_TILL="20141124" 
     APPLICATION="CTDS0320" 
     APPL_FORM="AFT" 
     APPL_TYPE="FILE_TRANS" 
     APPL_VER="6.1.01" 
     APR="1" 
     AUG="1" 
     AUTHOR="wyy" 
     AUTOARCH="0" 
     CHANGE_DATE="20190403" 
     CHANGE_TIME="141554" 
     CHANGE_USERID="ecsadmin" 
     CM_VER="610" 
     CONFIRM="0" 
     CREATION_DATE="20190328" 
     CREATION_TIME="105555" 
     CREATION_USER="singhm7" 
     CRITICAL="0" 
     CYCLIC="0" 
     CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0" 
     CYCLIC_TYPE="Interval" 
     DAYS_AND_OR="OR" 
     DEC="1" 
     DESCRIPTION="Processes Source data files FTP from Source System" 
     DOCLIB="/prod/appl/ctds/Doc" 
     DOCMEM="energent_billing_delta.doc" 
     FEB="1" 
     GROUP="@CTDS-BW" 
     IND_CYCLIC="START" 
     INTERVAL="00000M" 
     JAN="1" 
     JOBNAME="energent_billing_delta-FTP" 
     JUL="1" 
     JUN="1" 
     MAR="1" 
     MAXDAYS="0" 
     MAXRERUN="0" 
     MAXRUNS="0" 
     MAXWAIT="7" 
     MAY="1" 
     MEMLIB="Not in use for application jobs" 
     MEMNAME="energent_billing_delta-FTP" 
     MULTY_AGENT="N" 
     NODEID="vprv0320" 
     NOV="1" 
     OCT="1" 
     OWNER="ctds_energent" 
     PARENT_TABLE="@CTDS" 
     PRIORITY="AA" 
     RETRO="0" 
     RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="OR" 
     SEP="1" 
     SHIFT="IGNOREJOB" 
     SHIFTNUM="+00" 
     SYSDB="0" 
     TASKTYPE="Job" 
     USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N" 
     WEEKSCAL="BCD-Y">
      <INCOND AND_OR="AND" NAME="CTDS0320-ENERGENT-BILLING-DELTA-OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
      <OUTCOND NAME="CTDS0320-ENERGENT-BILLING-DELTA-FTP" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="ADD"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ACCOUNT" VALUE="ctds_energent"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LOSTYPE" VALUE="Unix"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LUSER" VALUE="ctds"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ROSTYPE" VALUE="Windows"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RUSER" VALUE="controlm@enbridge.com"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LPATH1" VALUE="/prod/appl/ctds/Publish/ENERGENT/*"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPATH1" VALUE="/\Business Intelligence-Gas Consumption\Energent\Outgoing\Gas Consumption\"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-PATH" VALUE="Not in use for application jobs"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-USE_DEF_NUMRETRIES" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPF" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CLEAR_ALL" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CONNTYPE2" VALUE="FTP"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CONNTYPE1" VALUE="LOCAL"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LHOST" VALUE="Local"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RHOST" VALUE="hdq-nt164"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LPASSIVE" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPASSIVE" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD2" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD3" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD4" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD5" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRANSFER_NUM" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE1" VALUE="A"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE2" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE3" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE4" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE5" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UNIQUE1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM2" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM3" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM4" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM5" VALUE="1"/>
    </JOB>
    <JOB
    ACTIVE_TILL="20141124" 
     APPLICATION="CTDS-VPRV0342" 
     APPL_FORM="AFT" 
     APPL_TYPE="FILE_TRANS" 
     APPL_VER="6.1.01" 
     APR="1" 
     AUG="1" 
     AUTHOR="wyy" 
     AUTOARCH="0" 
     CHANGE_DATE="20190716" 
     CHANGE_TIME="233201" 
     CHANGE_USERID="pahwar" 
     CM_VER="610" 
     CONFIRM="0" 
     CREATION_DATE="20190611" 
     CREATION_TIME="072632" 
     CREATION_USER="pahwar" 
     CRITICAL="0" 
     CYCLIC="0" 
     CYCLIC_TOLERANCE="0" 
     CYCLIC_TYPE="Interval" 
     DAYS_AND_OR="OR" 
     DEC="1" 
     DESCRIPTION="Processes Source data files FTP from Source System" 
     DOCLIB="/prod/appl/ctds/Doc/" 
     DOCMEM="energent_billing_delta.doc" 
     FEB="1" 
     GROUP="@CTDS-BW" 
     IND_CYCLIC="START" 
     INTERVAL="00000M" 
     JAN="1" 
     JOBNAME="energent_billing_delta-FTP" 
     JUL="1" 
     JUN="1" 
     MAR="1" 
     MAXDAYS="0" 
     MAXRERUN="0" 
     MAXRUNS="0" 
     MAXWAIT="7" 
     MAY="1" 
     MEMLIB="Not in use for application jobs" 
     MEMNAME="energent_billing_delta-FTP" 
     MULTY_AGENT="N" 
     NODEID="vprv0342" 
     NOV="1" 
     OCT="1" 
     OWNER="ctds_energent" 
     PARENT_TABLE="@CTDS-VPRV0342" 
     PRIORITY="AA" 
     RETRO="0" 
     RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="OR" 
     SEP="1" 
     SHIFT="IGNOREJOB" 
     SHIFTNUM="+00" 
     SYSDB="0" 
     TASKTYPE="Job" 
     USE_INSTREAM_JCL="N" 
     WEEKSCAL="BCD-Y">
      <INCOND AND_OR="AND" NAME="V0342-ENERGENT-BILLING-DELTA-OK" ODATE="ODAT"/>
      <OUTCOND NAME="V0342-ENERGENT-BILLING-DELTA-FTP" ODATE="ODAT" SIGN="ADD"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ACCOUNT" VALUE="ctds_energent"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LOSTYPE" VALUE="Unix"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LUSER" VALUE="ctds"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ROSTYPE" VALUE="Windows"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RUSER" VALUE="controlm@enbridge.com"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LPATH1" VALUE="/prod/appl/ctds/Publish/ENERGENT/*"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPATH1" VALUE="/\Business Intelligence-Gas Consumption\Energent\Outgoing\Gas Consumption\"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-PATH" VALUE="Not in use for application jobs"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-USE_DEF_NUMRETRIES" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPF" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CLEAR_ALL" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CONNTYPE2" VALUE="FTP"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-CONNTYPE1" VALUE="LOCAL"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LHOST" VALUE="Local"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RHOST" VALUE="hdq-nt164"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-LPASSIVE" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-RPASSIVE" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD2" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD3" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD4" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UPLOAD5" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRANSFER_NUM" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE1" VALUE="A"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE2" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE3" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE4" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TYPE5" VALUE="I"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-MINSIZE5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TIMELIMIT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-UNIQUE1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-IF_EXIST5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-SRCOPT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-DSTOPT5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME1" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME2" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME3" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME4" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-ABSTIME5" VALUE="0"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM1" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM2" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM3" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM4" VALUE="1"/>
      <AUTOEDIT2 NAME="%%FTP-TRIM5" VALUE="1"/>
    </JOB>
    <JOB
```

Regards,
Sriram.V

Answer (score 0):

The name is actually "%%FTP-RHOST" and not "FTP-RHOST". This also needs to go into double quotes and not single and so:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//JOB['"$i"']/AUTOEDIT2[@NAME="%%FTP-RHOST"]/@VALUE' ~testhwa/FTPJobstable007.xml >> /tmp/FTRSERVER
```

Comment: Yes, it was %%FTP-RHOST and I had in double quotes to accommodate it , tried single quotes as well and it was not working , so finally had it replaced in my original fine and parsed this way as shown in the question , but was still not working , anyway now I am doing it as ```xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//JOB/AUTOEDIT2[@NAME="%%FTP-RHOST"]' -v './@VALUE' -n ~testhwa/table-vpc-lx-004.xml >> /tmp/FTRSERVER```  and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//JOB/AUTOEDIT2[@NAME="%%FTP-RHOST"]' -v './@VALUE' -n ~testhwa/table-vpc-lx-004.xml >> /tmp/FTRSERVER
```

and this works perfectly.